# Video Compression Does not work for a live Capture

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

Following is my Filter Graph. I am trying to insert "ffdshow video encoder" encoder in the filtergraph, but I am unable to do so.[image]

Following is my Code for trying to Connect Compressor after getting filtergraph generated:

```
public void setFileName(string pFileName)
    {
        int hr;
        IBaseFilter _infinitePinTeeFilter = null;
        graph.FindFilterByName("Infinite Pin Tee Filter", out _infinitePinTeeFilter); 

        mediaControl.Stop();
        hr = captureGraphBuilder.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, pFileName, out mux, out sink);
        checkHR(hr, "Can't set SetOutputFile");
        hr = captureGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Video, _infinitePinTeeFilter, _videoCompressor, mux);
        checkHR(hr, "Can't Render Output File");
        mediaControl.Run();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ICaptureGraphBuilder::SetOutputFileName` is not a good choice of API to set the graph up. It does the job well for simple graphs, but as it forwards you back errors without good description and the stage at which the error actually happened, every time you have hard time trying to understand what goes wrong.

The problem might be caused by absence of frame rate information on the media type on the output of video compressor, but as the building stage you have on your screenshot you don't even have this media type yet available and you cannot troubleshoot and get this information.

Use `IGraphBuilder::AddFilter`, `IGraphBuilder::Connect`, `IFileSinkiFilter::SetFileName` instead to reliably configure the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It would be great if some code reference is given. Moreover, is it possible  that I can have video streaming, samplegrab and file saving (with compression) in the same graph?

Comment: The topology you are building can be completed and can work (in terms capture + preview + grabbing + recording at the same time in particular). AVI Mux might have its own requirements on media type, video compressor also has its own requirements. When you do a bulk operation `SetOutputFileName`/`RenderStream` to complete the graph, you don't see where it fails. Whn you add things incrementally one by one you can see this.

Comment: Thanks Man! You always help!!